# Heritage, dynamic binding, constructor in superclass. Java

Tags: java

How come the first System.out.println does not print a value of 10? It prints a 0. First a new Child-object is created which calls the constructor in Parent. The constructor in Parent calls lookup in Child because of dynamic binding. So why does lookup in Child return a zero and not a ten?

```
public class Main332 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Child child = new Child(); 
        System.out.println("child.value() returns " + child.value());//Prints 0

        Parent parent = new Child();
        System.out.println("parent.value() returns " + parent.value());//Prints 0

        Parent parent2 = new Parent();
        System.out.println("parent2.value() returns " + parent2.value());//Prints 5
    }
}


public class Child extends Parent { 
    private int num = 10; 

    public int lookup() {
        return num;
    }
}


public class Parent {
    private int val;

    public Parent() {
        val = lookup();
    }

    public int value() {
        return val;
    }

    public int lookup() {
        return 5;// Silly
    } 
}
```

Comment: How come when I change num in Child to static I get the value 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field initializer for `num` in `Child` is executed *after* the constructor call in `Parent`. Therefore `lookup()` returns 0, so `Parent.val` is set to 0.

To observe this, change `Child.lookup()` to print out what it's about to return.

See [section 12.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) for details of the order of execution when creating a new instance.